# Jenkins: stash vs archiveArtifacts

Tags: jenkins

What are the use cases and pros/cons for using `stash` vs `archiveArtifacts`?

The documentation mentions each:

i.e. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

and

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/

but doesn't do a comparison.

Comment: Stashed files are discarded at the end of the build, artifacts aren't.

Answer (score 3):

`stash` is used to "save" some files in a pipeline stage and reuse them on a different slave (`unstash`). Stash is only useful when you have a small set of files. It will become very slow when you want to stash a big amount of data. If you need to stash a lot of files it's recommended to use a shared filesystem between your slaves so the content of your workspace can be used by multiple slaves.

Archiving artifacts will save artifacts on the master slave. You can specify if you only want to archive the generated artifacts from the last build or more. This is useful when you have some deploy job on your master to deploy the artifacts after a succesful run or to make them available in your jenkins console.

Answer (score 1):

From the latest Pipeline Syntax documentation and Options directive:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

**preserveStashes**

> Preserve stashes from completed builds, for use with stage restarting. For example: options { preserveStashes() } to preserve the stashes from the most recent completed build, or options { preserveStashes(buildCount: 5) } to preserve the stashes from the five most recent completed builds.

In theory this seems much the same as using archiveArtifacts with buildDiscarder option to apply artifact retention policy.